# Generate Tessellation & Centroids using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, centroids, tesselation

I first generated a square tessellation (using [Generate Tesselation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/generatetesellation.htm)) using the following:

```
arcpy.GenerateTessellation_management(Output_Feature_Class="/File Location Removed", Extent="371935.1483 411977.256099999 1618490.2735 1596583.8365", Shape_Type="SQUARE", Size="1 SquareKilometers", Spatial_Reference="PROJCS['NAD_1983_Texas_Statewide_Mapping_System',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Lambert_Conformal_Conic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',1000000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',1000000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-100.0],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',27.41666666666667],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_2',34.91666666666666],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',31.16666666666667],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-37624400 -27099700 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision")
```

Now I am needing to add centroid coordinates for each grid using ArcGIS Pro.

I have tried to use add geometry attributes, polygon to point, and using Python code in ArcGISPro. I also tried using (using [How To: Find the centroid of polygons using Calculate Geometry](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000009381)). However, I keep getting the same centroid information for all of the individual grids.

Comment: What parameters did you use with Create Fishnet?  There is a checkbox that outputs the centroids as a second feature class of points.

Comment: I actually used Generate Tessellation to create the grid and then select by location the grids that intersect my location.

Comment: My request for clarification then becomes "What parameters did you use with Generate Tesselation and how precisely did you try to add centroid information?"  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to provide any requested clarifications.

Comment: Make sure that all polygons is not in fact one big multipart polygon

Comment: Very busy day and had limited time to look at this issue, but I do believe it is one large polygon. However, when I add centroids it will add a point in each grid. So my attribute table shows over 700,000 individual coordinates for each grid. But, the coordinates are all identical.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a Square tessellation, added X and Y fields (DOUBLE as data type) and ran code below. Could you try this on your data:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("GenerateTessellation",['X','Y','SHAPE@XY']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=row[2][0]
        row[1]=row[2][1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that worked---I had to do before I clipped the grid to my state shapefile.

Comment: Could you mark my answer as solution if it solved your problem